# make json from params hash

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I am trying to call API and pass data to it from the `form` in my `view` to `controller` and then call API with `post` method.

What I get in `params` is:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kLLaVRc6kcndkfB1nkntSTzGCg95CMCT1UvEncqwLgc=", 

"score_sheet"=>{

  "score_sheet_master"=>{

    "issue_date(1i)"=>"2014", "issue_date(2i)"=>"6", "issue_date(3i)"=>"27"}, 

  "print_date(1i)"=>"2014", "print_date(2i)"=>"6", "print_date(3i)"=>"27", "product_id"=>"2", "pull_id"=>"2", "press_run_id"=>"1", "total_section"=>"2", 

  "score_sheet_sections_attributes"=>{

    "0"=>{"section_name"=>"A", "total_pages"=>"2", "color_pages"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 

    "1"=>{"section_name"=>"B", "total_pages"=>"1", "color_pages"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}},   

  "color_pages_rated"=>"1", "bw_pages_rated"=>"2", "foreman_id"=>"", "pic_id"=>""}, 

  "score_sheet_master"=>{

    "press_id"=>"1"}, 

  "commit"=>"Create Score sheet"}
```

I want this Hash to be converted into the Following `JSON` which `APIs` accept. i-e.

```
{
    "score_sheet": {
        "score_sheet_master": {
            "issue_date": "2014-06-25",
            "press_id": "1"
        },
        "print_date": "2014-06-23",
        "product_id": 1,
        "pull_id": 2,
        "press_run_id": 1,
        "total_section": 2,
        "score_sheet_sections_attributes": [
            {
                "section_name": "A",
                "total_pages": 3,
                "color_pages": "2,3",
                "id": 9
            },
            {
                "section_name": "B",
                "total_pages": 1,
                "color_pages": "1",
                "id": 10
            },
            {
                "section_name": "C",
                "total_pages": 2,
                "color_pages": "2"
            }
        ],
        "pic_id": 1,
        "foreman_id": 1
    }
}
```

Some the fields in JSON might be missing or may be more than the HASH but I don't have concern with that I will handle them personally the main issue is to convert this params Hash to the required JSON. **Hold On** I have implemented the `date conversion` thing that is working fine. but **don't know how to convert `score_sheet_sections_attributes` array format to the required format**.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Got it myself:

```
sections = []
params["score_sheet"]["score_sheet_sections_attributes"].each {|k,v| sections << v}
params["score_sheet"]["score_sheet_sections_attributes"] = sections
```

Which gives:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kLLaVRc6kcndkfB1nkntSTzGCg95CMCT1UvEncqwLgc=", "score_sheet"=>{"score_sheet_master"=>{"issue_date(1i)"=>"2014", "issue_date(2i)"=>"6", "issue_date(3i)"=>"27"}, "print_date(1i)"=>"2014", "print_date(2i)"=>"6", "print_date(3i)"=>"27", "product_id"=>"2", "pull_id"=>"2", "press_run_id"=>"1", "total_section"=>"2", "score_sheet_sections_attributes"=>[{"section_name"=>"A", "total_pages"=>"2", "color_pages"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}, {"section_name"=>"B", "total_pages"=>"1", "color_pages"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}], "color_pages_rated"=>"1", "bw_pages_rated"=>"2", "foreman_id"=>"", "pic_id"=>""}, "score_sheet_master"=>{"press_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Score sheet"}
```

and for dates I have another logic implemented and all done.